# Regexp match newlines to first match

Tags: php, regex

I need regexp for match all newlines to first match.

Example text:

```
<p>[Block 1]</p>
<h4>Heading</h4>
<p>Dolor</p>
<p>Ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem</p>
<p>[Block2]</p>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Example</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Example</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I wrote this regexp

```
/<p>\[(.*)\]<\/p>(.*?)/gm
```

But this regexp doesn't match newlines to first match.
I need array:

```
[0] =>
     [0]=>'Block 1';
     [1]=>'...Html code... before next [block #]';
[1] =>
     [0]=>'Block 2';
     [1]=>'...Html code... before next [block #]';
```

Comment: This a typical question to match text between two same patterns or end of string, use `'/<p>\[(.*?)]<\/p>(.*?)(?=<p>\[.*?]<\/p>|\z)/s'`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/WcbDZn/1).

Comment: "Match newlines to first match" ? Anyway, you should use a DOM parser for this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much! Could you post as answer? I'll mark it.